# Trouble instantiating db SQLAlchemy when importing table class definitions

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a SQLAlchemy python sqlite application with different modules for defining schema, instantiating the database, and adding records from parsing CSV files.  The only way I can get the database to instantiate with any tables is if the table classes are created in the same module as my Base.metadata.create_all() call.  I have seen examples online where there is a db_init function in a separate module that imports the table classes and then generates the DB structure, but for me I get a completely empty db.

I'd rather do it this way so I can reuse the model.py for the module where I import the data.  The examples I have found seem to come from Flask, but this is not a Flask app.  I am using sqlalchemy directly.

An example of my models.py (just one class):

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Date, Text, String, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from db2 import Base

class Area(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'areas'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64), unique=True)
```

And db2.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import os

Base = declarative_base()


def db_create(conn_string):
    engine = create_engine(conn_string)
    from models import Area, Audit, CardsPerArea, Issue, Pareto
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

But this gives me an empty db.  If I move all the content of models.py into the db2.py, the database is built out.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is being caused by a circular import in your code.  This can be solved by moving the call to `declarative_base()` from db2.py into models.py.

models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Date, Text, String, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Area(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'areas'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64), unique=True)
```

db2.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os
import models

def db_create(conn_string):
    engine = create_engine(conn_string)
    models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```